# How to set magit remember git passphrase on Windows?

Tags: magit

I run `magit` on Linux and it works very well. On Windows, it works almost the same except the push process:

Git Bash would ask me to enter `passphrase` to continue, while magit just hangs.

I set `ssh-agent` to remember passphrase on git bash. But it has no effect on magit.

Is there a way to let magit remember passphrase?

**Edit**

I use `SSH`, not `HTTPS`. So the github credential helper won't work.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible from Magit (although I don't see how it could store the password securely *and* not bug you for an access-password all the time), but you can use a 'credential helper' on Windows: https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/#platform-windows

Comment: I am a tired of this question. It has been asked and answered so many times. Have a look at the FAQ or search SE. It would also be nice if one of the many Windows users having problems with this would not only kinda solve the issue for himself, but invest some time to investigate the issue further and then share his improved solution.

Comment: @SeanAllred Thank you for your help. I use SSH. The `credential helper`is useful for HTTPS (user name / passward). I think I need to figure out `magit` and `ssh-agent` cooperations. (ssh-agent works well for git-bash.)

Comment: Then I'm frankly not sure why you need a password… though it's been a while since I used Windows regularly for development work.

Comment: @SeanAllred Not a password, it's the passphrase setted at the stage of generating ssh rsa key. I guess many people left this passphrase blank.

Comment: @Nick Have you followed https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/ exactly?

Comment: @SeanAllred Yes, this is exactly the page I referenced when I generate SSH Key. After the last step, I got the expected "sucessfully authenticated." On linux, everything works. On Windows, (yes, I generated ssh key again.) I have to manually input passphrase to git-bash each time I `push`. Magit just hangs there.

Comment: Magit will hang there unless you use http auth.  It might be a path issue – I don't know.  Windows and Git-Bash complicates things – do you have Cygwin installed?  Where does Git-Bash think `HOME` is? (As in `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`)

Comment: @SeanAllred `$HOME` is set to  `c:/Users/Nick`, Git-Bash works fine with this. I don't have cygwin installed. I need to do some research on cygwin git and git-bash. (Linux is really great platform for these developping tools.) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by:

1. Remove Git-Bash.
2. Install '[GitHub](https://windows.github.com/)'. GitHub will add two shortcuts on desktop:

   -**GitHub**: for GUI.

   -**Git Shell**: An integretated PowerShell with git and other commands.
3. Check 'Git Shell' destination. On my system, it is:

   ```
   C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c2ba306e536fdf878271f7fe636a147ff37326ad\bin
   ```
4. Add this dir to `$Path`. Voila, `Magit` in Emacs could push without any problem.

**Other resources**

1. [Generating SSH](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/)
2. [Working with SSH key passphrases](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/)

Comment: Can you please accept your answer so this question can be marked as answered?